# MS Office - why is certain functionality locked in protected mode. Sorting, Filtering, View, etc

Tags: microsoft-office

This has bothered me in some time. I can't figure out why would "Protected View" prevent me from using excel functionality that is only related to how data are presented. For example; why would "Data->Filter" be grayed out, or "View->Freeze Panes" or various other functionality which, in essence, is read-only. Same applies to other MS office products as well.
[image]

Comment: I would guess it is because those functions interact with the file in a way that Protected Mode doesn't allow. Perhaps looking up documentation on Protected Mode may help explain this. Have you done that yet?

Comment: @music2myear, I have searched for "Protected View" documentation/info but what I found only relates to the general reason why this feature exists and how to use it rather than a detailed specification as to why certain sub features are allowed and certain others are not.